# freebsd make install openjdk6

Tags: freebsd, java

I am having problem installing openjdk6 using ports using the `make install clean` commands. The error I got is:

> /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i586-debug-fastdebug/j2sdk-image: No such file or directory

edited:

```
freebsd# file /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i586-debug-fastdebug/j2sdk-image: cannot open '/usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i586-debug-fastdebug/j2sdk-image' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Post the whole transcript. Post the output of `file /usr/ports/java/openjdk6/work/build/bsd-i586-debug-fastdebug/j2sdk-image`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/ports/java/openjdk6 
make config ( off FASTDEBUG )
make install clean
```